# Yii2 установка плагинов для ckeditor

Tags: yii2, плагин, ckeditor, composer

Использую [ckeditor](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget) от 2amigos.

Каким образом нужно устанавливать плагины в этот виджет?

Для примера хочу установить плагин [Spoiler](http://ckeditor.com/addon/spoiler)

как должно это выглядеть в проекте?

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста какой плагин конкретно используете

Comment: ckeditor от амигос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Для начала нужно создать новую папку в **@webroot** вашего проекта. Для примера назовем папку **ckeditor**. Внутри этой папки создаем папку **plugins** и кидаем все плагины, которые хотим использовать для дальнейшей работы.
2. В созданной нами папке создаем **config.js** с содержимым

   ```
   CKEDITOR.plugins.basePath = '/ckeditor/plugins/';

   CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
   config.extraPlugins = 'spoiler';
   };
   ```
3. В представлении при подключении настраиваем:

   ```
   <?= $form->field($model, 'text')->widget(CKEditor::className(), ['preset' => 'standart',
       'clientOptions' => [
           'customConfig' => '/ckeditor/config.js',
       ]]) ?>
   ```

**P.S.** Структуру папок и название файла конфигурации Вы можете настроить на свое усмотрение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что считать вебрут в шаблоне бэйсик? можно скрин фаловой системы?

Comment: webroot это папка web

Comment: и при скачивании предположим спойлер скачиваются две папки - спойлер и инклуд. какая система должна быть плагины-спойлер- папки спойлер и инклуд?

Comment: web/ckeditor/plugins/spoiler/...

Comment: я скрин проекта приложил. что куда ложить?

Comment: прикрепил к ответу. в вопросе можешь убрать)